# How do I obscure a password in a Camel configuration file

Tags: apache-camel

I am looking at using the Camel [crypto tool](http://camel.apache.org/crypto.html) for processing PGP data but have a requirement that the password to the keys used be either encrypted in the configuration file or be sourced from a secure server elsewhere.  Is this possible without generating my own PGP processor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes see the security menu on the Apache Camel web site: http://camel.apache.org/security.html

There is a section about configuration security, where you can use camel-jasypt for that: http://camel.apache.org/jasypt.html

This allows you to store encrypted usernames / passwords etc in a .properties file, and then you can refer to these properties from Camel crypto, using Camel's property placeholder: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html